# How to access children values of a JObject

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a JObject item that looks like this:

```
{

        "part":
         {
             "values": ["engine","body","door"]
             "isDelivered": "true"
        },
        {
        "manufacturer":
         {
             "values": ["Mercedes"]
             "isDelivered": "false" 
         }
}
```

How can I get the values as a single string in C#?

Comment: How do you want to combine the items? Comma separated, for example? Do you mean you want all values from all objects, or just like `part > values` and `manufacturer > values` as separate value strings?

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I want to save the keys e.g. part and then the values underneath as they are in the row, i.e. a simple array

Comment: the question is still not clear to me. could you post how the output should be?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First create JObject from your string

```
String json = "{\"part\":{ \"values\": [\"engine\",\"body\",\"door\"], \"isDelivered\": \"true\"},\"manufacturer\":{\"values\": [\"Mercedes\"],\"isDelivered\": \"false\"}}";
JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
```

Then get values array (from part for example as)

```
JArray jArray= (JArray)jObject["part"]["values"];
```

Convert JArray of String to string array

```
string[] valuesArray = jArray.ToObject<string[]>();
```

Join your string array & create a singe string

```
String values = string.Join(",",valuesArray);
```

Full code here  ..

```
String json = "{\"part\":{ \"values\": [\"engine\",\"body\",\"door\"], \"isDelivered\": \"true\"},\"manufacturer\":{\"values\": [\"Mercedes\"],\"isDelivered\": \"false\"}}";
JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
JArray jArray= (JArray)jObject["part"]["values"];
string[] valuesArray = jArray.ToObject<string[]>();
String values = string.Join(",",valuesArray);
Console.WriteLine(values);
```

Answer (score 2):

First things first, that json is not properly formatted, it should be:

```
{
    "part":
    {
        "values": ["engine","body","door"],
        "isDelivered": "true"
    },
    "manufacturer":
    {
        "values": ["Mercedes"],
        "isDelivered": "false" 
    }
}
```

Now, getting to the answer, I believe this is what you want

```
var jObject = JObject.Parse(testJson);
var children = jObject.Children().Children();
var valuesList = new List<string>();
foreach (var child in children)
{
    valuesList.AddRange(child["values"].ToObject<List<string>>());
}
var valuesJsonArray = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(valuesList); // not sure if you want an array of strings or a json array of strings
```